# Convert a hexadecimal list into an array of integers in Dart

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

I'm looking to convert a hexadecimal list into an array of integers in Dart. The same way it is done in Kotlin shown below.

```
private val METHOD_TRANSFORM = byteArrayOf(0xA1.toByte(), 0x2E.toByte(), 0x38.toByte(), 0xD4.toByte(), 0x89.toByte())
```

However, I'm confused around the correct method to implement it. From my understanding reading this article: https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-bytes-in-dart-6ece83455721 I can convert a single hex code into a integer through using the `int myInt = int.parse('hex', radix: 16);` method.

My first question is how can I do this for an entire list in Dart without copying and pasting the same code multiple times for each hex code?

Secondly, the `0xA1.toByte()` method in Kotlin converts the hex code into a signed integer. Would converting the hex code into a unassigned integer instead i.e. a `Uint8List` array be any different?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you could modify or map every value in a list by using the map method:

```dart
final foo = <String>['0xffba'];
final bar = foo.map((item) => int.parse(item, radix: 16)).toList();
```